# split an anyobject in swift

Tags: swift, split

I want to get the userinfo of my locale notification.
I do it like this way:

```
var app:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications {
        var notification = oneEvent as! UILocalNotification
        ate = gregorian.dateFromComponents(comps)!

        var OldUUID = notification.userInfo
    }
}
```

The Result is:

```
{UUID = WhmMbGrCkJ;}"
```

But I only want this part: WhmMbGrCkJ
I try something like that:

```
        var OldUUID = notification.userInfo
        var OldUUIDSplit = OldUUID.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
        var OldUUIDSplit2 = OldUUIDSplit[1].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        var OldUUIDSplit3 = OldUUIDSplit2.componentsSeparatedByString(";")
        var NewOldUUID = OldUUIDSplit3[0]
```

i get this error:

> Cannot invoke 'componentsSeparatedByString' with an argument list of type '(String)'

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job. userInfo is just a dictionary so you can fetch value by key:

```
if let dict = notification.userInfo, OldUUID = dict["UUID"] {
    println("\(OldUUID)")
}
```

Comment: then i get this error: Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: @Ghost108 sorry my mistake, userInfo is an optional dictionary so you have to unwrap it as well. See edited answer.

Comment: same error :(  Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: Can you try this: let OldUUID = notification.userInfo!["UUID"]!

Comment: Can you review the code from my answer it should works too, it's safer way to get the value that the one I put in comment.